# Is there a node.js (server) compatible ZLIB.deflate implementation for the browser (client)

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, zlib, deflate

I want to deflate very big JSON objects client side (plus base64 encription) and then inflate them on a node.js server with

```
zlib.inflate( new Buffer( postData, 'base64'), function( err, result ) {
...
)}
```

Is there any really (!) working implementation for client side deflating out there? I have not found one yet.

Comment: How about the `zlib` module? Is it not working for you? http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html

Comment: Have you tried http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/2009/09/29/jsxcompressor-zlib-compressed-javascript-code/ ?

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis heinob is asking about client-side code, and IIRC nodejs zlib is implemented in C

Comment: @Nirk: No I haven't, but I will and let you know the result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nirk: The JavaScript part of JSXgraph is for decompression only. Beware that the author mixes up deflation and inflation on the info page. This is a common mistake.

Comment: @heinob thanks for trying that out :)  I wish there was a review site for javascript modules ...

Comment: @heinob i meant more like user ratings

Comment: @Nirk: Good idea! Github or npm with ratings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a solution that works perfectly and is also lightning fast:

https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js/blob/develop/README.en.md